# Unable to install wine on Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: apt, software-installation, wine

So I've tried to install `wine` following the instructions on developer's site https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and got an error:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libtasn1-6 i386 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1   404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libgnutls30 i386 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.2
Err:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libpulse0 i386 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2   404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libtasn1-6 i386 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1   404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libgnutls30 i386 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.2   404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-6/libtasn1-6_4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls30_3.4.10-4ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/libpulse0_8.0-0ubuntu3.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Tried to install with `--fix-missing` - same thing

```
ping 213.180.204.183 - 0% packet loss
```

Were some packages deleted from official repository? How can I fix that?

**Update 1**
After `sudo apt update` I have this:

```
After this operation, 278 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libtasn1-6 i386 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a02:6b8::183 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libgnutls30 i386 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.2
Err:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libpulse0 i386 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a02:6b8::183 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libtasn1-6 i386 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a02:6b8::183 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libgnutls30 i386 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.2
  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a02:6b8::183 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtasn1-6/libtasn1-6_4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.1_i386.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a02:6b8::183 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls30_3.4.10-4ubuntu1.2_i386.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a02:6b8::183 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/libpulse0_8.0-0ubuntu3.2_i386.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to ru.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2a02:6b8::183). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a02:6b8::183 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**Update 2**
https://paste.ubuntu.com/25057105/

Comment: i think your source.list file is corrupted.

Comment: @DavidFoerster first of all thank you for editing my post.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I will use code listing format now. 
I have updated with `sudo apt update` and now I've got something new. The log is too big to post here, so I'm going to edit my ticket.

Comment: @DavidFoerster [all logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_T5WvbcbVBfZjVMckZsSG82cGM)

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for helping me, David. actually I don't even know what armhf architecture is.  can all this mess be a result of adding some strings to blacklist files? I was trying to get blender rendering on gpu cuda drivers, so I used some help of this guy https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342538&p=13615429#post13615429 
I'm just guessing if it could cause such problems with wine installation.

Comment: @DavidFoerster so I did what you've just said, then I've upgraded the system and installed wine. it works fine! Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: Reviewers please be careful reviewing this question because there have been many new comments and a link to logs posted in a comment after this question was first reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local package list is obviously outdated because there are issues with the package sources configuration: Canonical's repositories and their mirrors don't provide armhf packages. Since you don't need to enable the armhf architecture on your system on top of amd64 and i386 you can disable it:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```

Now update the package list and resume the installation:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```